# How to stop "Open relay" function on smtp server

Tags: email, smtp, webserver, webmail

I am seeing the **via centsol.com** in some one's mail who has no access to **centsol smtp server**. I googled it and found that this issue is related to "**Open relay**" function of **smtp**. So my question is how to resolve this issue?
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Well it really depends on what system you're using for sending mail.

Exchange Server: http://www.techrepublic.com/article/prevent-open-relays-on-exchange-server/

If you're using postfix or something else, the fix could be a lot more complicated than that.

Comment: My webserver is deployed on Ipage server and running ubuntu so in that case what can i do?